# Unable to install GRUB in /Dev/sdb2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I used to have windows and ubuntu working togther on my laptop which has two hard disks, the first one is ssd and it includes Windows and the second one is hdd partioned into four partions one of them is for Ubuntu and they were working fine, but after I tried to install a new version of Ubuntu it keeps showing me the message "this is a fatal error"and after restart I got into rescue GRUB prompt. now I can't boot from either of the systems. following are the error message and the list of my partions.

Error message
[image]

Partitions lists
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That partitions are shown as unknown may indicate fast start up or hibernation is on in Windows. Or Windows bitlocker is on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation